# Directional derivative of $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2-z^2$ at $(3,4,5)$ along the curve of intersection of $2x^2+2y^2-z^2=25$ and $x^2+y^2=z^2$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Directional derivative of $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2-z^2$ at $(3,4,5)$ along the curve of intersection of the two surfaces $2x^2+2y^2-z^2=25$ and $x^2+y^2=z^2$.

**Attempt:**

The curve of intersection of $2x^2+2y^2-z^2=25$ and $x^2+y^2=z^2$ is $z=\pm 5$

Directional derivative of $f = \bigtriangledown f(3,4,5)\cdot \widehat u$ where $\widehat u$ is the unit vector along the curve $z=\pm 5$.

Now, there are infinite unit vectors along the curve $z=\pm 5$, so, how do I choose one?

Thank you very much for your help in this regard.

Comment: For each point in the curve you can find the expression for the tangent vector, then it is just take the norm. But you can find the value in (3,4,5), then is enough compute the vector in that point.

Comment: Uhm, Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Your curve has the implicity expression given by $x^2+y^2=25$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z=\pm 5$ is not a curve. Of course, $2x^2+2y^2-z^2=25$ and $x^2+y^2=z^2$ imply $z=\pm 5$, but don't forgot about $x$ and $y$. I'll show case $z=5$, $z=-5$ is similar.

If $z=5$, then $x^2+y^2=25$, so you can parametrize curve this way:

$$(x,y,z)=(5\sin t, 5\cos t, 5)$$

Now put $x=5\sin t, y=5\cos t, z=5$ into $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2-z^2$. You get function of one variable:

$$g(t)=f(x,y,z)=25\sin^2 t+ 25\cos^2 t -25=0$$

Finally calculate derivative of this function. It's directional derivative which you find.

$$g'(t)=0$$

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain why we needed to get a function of one variable?

Comment: It's only one way of solving questions like this. But if you find parametrization of curve and put it into equation you know something about function behavior along this curve.

Comment: Ohkay.. So, $g~'(t) = 0 $ as $g(t) = 0$ is a constant function,   And actually, there was no use of finding the gradient. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, this way you can't find gradient. But you don't need gradient, only directional derivative. So you are right.

Comment: Oh okay. I asked because traditionally directional derivative is $\bigtriangledown f(a) \cdot \widehat u$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.